# restful routes from flash builder http service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm new to Flash Builder. I'm trying to access a RESTful url and manage the returned data. I'm using http data/services access and I have got a backend in Ruby on Rails.

I found out that I should use curly brackets ({}) for the parameters in the url. For example `http://restfulService/{items}/{itemID}`
 then flex automaticaly makes the table with service parameters.
http://s18.postimage.org/ihifv02qx/http.jpg
 Then in the application I get a function

```
protected function itemGrid_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    ItemsIndexResult.token = items.ItemsIndex(/*Enter value(s) for */ items, itemID);   
}
```

I'm a bit confused with the flex data service access. On every tutorial I found there where stict urls as strings. My question is how to store data from the http service call for example in datagrid by dataprovider when the url is restful. For example when user choose one type of items (kindofitem/1/item/1/item.xml) then they will be displayed in the grid and when the user chooses another type (kindofitem/2/item/1/item.xml), items with other type will be displayed. The difference between url in this two calls is just one parameter.

I would be grateful for any explanation or clue.

Comment: I think you'll have to show more code and provide more explanation.  Curly brackets in a URL have nothing to do with Flex.  Unless you have the URL defined in MXML somehow and are using binding to create your URL.  Flex does not automatically make any sort of table that I'm aware of.  When is your function called?  where is it located in the context of the rest of your code? You want to manage **WHAT** to get connected data?  Where is the code that calls the web service? Where is your result handler?

Comment: Thanks for a reply. I've edited the question. I hope it will be more understandable now.